# How to Combine ARMA + GARCH For Estimates + CI in Python

Tags: time-series, python, arima, garch, prediction-interval

I know I'm trekking down a well beaten path with this type of question, but I find myself trying to clarify how to combine several snippets on the internet and coming up empty handed.  There is one question very similar [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341353/how-to-make-forecast-with-confidence-intervals-with-arma-garch-model-in-python), but it does not have an answer.

My situation is very similar to the linked question.  That is:

- I'm working in python so `rugarch` and similar libraries are off the table
- I'd like to combine the outputs of an `ARMA` + `GARCH` model to make an estimate + CI

Most of the tutorials I see online in python strike me as misguided, because they are misspecifying various things.

Here's some sample code to get an example working:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pmdarima
import arch

# download data
ticker    = yf.Ticker('^GSPC')

data      = ticker.history(period = 'max')
vals      = np.log(data.iloc[:, 3]).diff()
vals.iloc[0] = 0

# fit ARIMA and GARCH models
arima     = pmdarima.auto_arima(X)
residuals = arima.arima_res_.resid * 100
garch     = arch.arch_model(residuals, p = 1, q = 1, dist = 'ged')
garch_fit = garch.fit()
garch_for = garch_fit.forecast(horizon = 1)
mean      = arima.predict(n_periods = 1)[0]
```

I am familiar with Richard Hardy's advice to git ARMA/GARCH simultaneously, but I am omitting that step for now.

Now, with these fitted models in hand, I continually run into conflicting information.

The first is how you combine the outputs of both into a single prediction.  What I frequently see online (in the python ecosystem, using the above libraries), is you take the `ARMA` prediction (the `mean` variable in this case), and then you add it to the predicted mean from `GARCH`.

So in this case it would look something like this:

```
# ARMA prediction + GARCH mean prediction for next time step, divided by 100 to scale
mean + forecast.mean['h.1'].iloc[-1] / 100
```

This has to be wrong, right?  For one, GARCH models are built on the assumption of a constant mean, and so this value is always the same, so I don't see what effect it would have.  I'd think it'd have to be adding the `ARMA` term + forecasted variance.  In this case it would look like:

```
# ARMA prediction + GARCH mean prediction for next time step, divided by 100 to scale
mean + forecast.variance['h.1'].iloc[-1] / 100
```

And the second is that it strikes me as odd that you would add this value and not subtract it as well.  Variance does not have a particular direction, so wouldn't you need to both add and subtract to get the range of values?

Likewise, if we want a true confidence interval, shouldn't we take the standard deviation of the variance?

So something like `sd = np.sqrt(forecast.variance['h.1'])` and then the confidence interval is `mean +/- 1.96 * sd`, or something like that?

I know there are a lot of questions here on this very topic, but I don't see any of them specified in this way.

Comment: You're looking for *prediction* (not confidence) intervals, right? Do you only need the 1-step ahead? In the GARCH setting the 1-step ahead distribution is trivial to derive because $\sigma^2_t$ is known exactly at $t-1$, whereas for longer horizons it's typically easier to use simulation.

Comment: Related: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352654/how-to-make-h-step-interval-forecasts-from-an-arma-garch-model/352665#352665) and perhaps [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352840/multistep-prediction-interval-for-armap-q-process/352845#352845).

Comment: Prediction intervals for ARMA-GARCH models are indeed more complex than one might assume. There is a very good paper dealing with this topic: Baillie, Bollerslev  (1992):  "Prediction in dynamic models with time-dependent conditional variances", Journal of Econometrics. I suggest that you read through this paper.